# Need help on dynamically creating navigation links based on content created in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6, umbraco7

i am very much new in Umbraco CMS and started coding in it recently. My page structure is like this[image]

And now I have written the code like this to generate the dynamic navigation based on the code I have found in Umbraco forums. But in output it is giving only the 'Home' as the link not other links.The reason is that I have written it like this { var homeNode = Model.AncestorOrSelf(1); } and it is only returning home page not other pages. i have tried using this also  Model.AncestorOrSelf(). But it is giving same result.

```
<nav>
    <ul>

        @{ var homeNode = Model.AncestorOrSelf(1); }

        <li><a href="@homeNode.Url" class="@Library.If(homeNode.Id == Model.Id, "selected", "")">@homeNode.Name</a></li>

        @foreach (var page in Model.Children.Where("Visible"))
        {
            var isSelected = false;
            if (Model.Id == page.Id || (Model.Parent != null && Model.Parent.Id == page.Id && Model.NodeTypeAlias != "Textpage"))
            {
                isSelected = true;
            }

            <li>
                <a href="@page.Url" class="@Library.If(isSelected, "selected", "")">@page.Name</a>

                <!-- If the page has child nodes (2nd level) that are visible and docTypeAlias is Textpage (textpages) -->
                @if (page.Textpages.Where("Visible").Count() > 0)
                {
                    <ul>
                        @foreach (var childPage in page.Children.Where("Visible"))
                        {
                            <li><a href="@childPage.Url" class="@Library.If(childPage.Id == Model.Id, "selected", "")">@childPage.Name</a></li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</nav>
```

What will be the proper expression to traverse this.

Thanks and Regards

utpal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so the first thing you want is to change your site hierarchy to this:

```
Home
|-- About Us
|-- Contact Us
|-- Services
```

You can find in *Document Types*, under *Settings* in the home node'S document type, the *Structure* tab to add the allowed node children node types to make the home node have allowed children of the 3 types you have.

Next you'll want this code to reach your home node:

```
var homeNode = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf("Site");
```

Where "Site" is your home node's document type.

Next you can prepare the data you'll want to loop:

```
var menuItems = homeNode.children.Where(x => x.IsVisible());
```

Finally you can change your loop to this:

```
@foreach (var page in menuItems)
```

This should help you get this to work.